# while loops and variables

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, updating

I am solving a problem where if someone has k snacks, he/she can get one bonus snack from exchanging the snack package.

For example if I have 8 snacks in the beginning and I will get one bonus snack if I exchange 3 snack packages, I'll end up with 11 snacks, since I get two from the 8 I have, and one more from the four snacks left. I made a program that should be correct, and I have tried the program manually.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t, n1, input, k, bonus = 0, total=0, bis =0;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--){
        scanf("%d", &input);
        scanf("%d", &k);
        n1 = input;
        while(input>=k){
        bonus = bonus + input/k;
        input = bonus + (input-(k*(input/k)));
        }
        total = n1 + bonus;
        printf("%d\n", total);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `t` is for the test cases and `input` is for the number of snacks someone has in the first place.

I've tried searching the problem, and it seems that the value of variable `input` in the while loop when I assign another input in it will result in making the `input` variable return big random numbers or something related to memory.

What is the real mistake I am doing here? and How can I solve it?

---

- t -- number of types to repeat the test
- input -- number of snacks owned initially
- k -- number of snacks needed to get a bonus

Comment: Can you post your assignment text instead of explaining it? your explanations are unclear

Comment: I'm sorry, let me explain it better

Comment: I don't understand "... and one more from the four snacks left."

Comment: the k is for my example, 3. So if I have 8 snacks in the beginning, I can exchange 6 snack packages for 2 bonus snacks, which leaves me with 4 snacks left (since I ate 6 to exchange the package, so I have two left, plus two from the bonus), I can exchange the 3 snack packages for another snack, which make me have altogether 8+2+1 snack

Comment: Did you get correct output for the first test? What is the incorrect output from the test, and what was the input to that test?

Comment: The correct output was 11, if the input was 1 8 3, the output I got was -2129593602

Comment: @ChrisW I already did what you said about moving the variable initialization, it worked for other test cases, the 1 8 3 is still giving wrong output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that `bonus` etc. need to be reinitialized to zero inside the loop i.e. before very test.

In fact I'd move the declarations of these variables -- of every variable except `t` -- to inside the loop.

And `bonus` should be reset inside the inner loop. If you don't have a debugger, walk through it line by line with pencil and paper and write down the value in each variable. It seemed to me after a brief inspection that with an input value of 11 and 3, when you run the current code the bonus will just get bigger and bigger, so it loops 1000s of times eventually the integer overflows to negative.

A more correct verion might be something like (untested):

```
int main()
{
    int t; 
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--){
        int input, k;
        scanf("%d", &input);
        scanf("%d", &k);
        int n1 = input;
        while(input>=k){
            int bonus = input/k;
            input += bonus - (k*bonus);
        }
        int total = n1 + bonus;
        printf("%d\n", total);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note this avoids declaring variables before they're initialized.

---

Edit to add:

I don't think the above solution is right. Perhaps it should be something more like (still untested):

```
int main()
{
    int t; 
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--){
        int input, k;
        scanf("%d", &input);
        scanf("%d", &k);
        int n1 = input;
        int bonus = 0;
        while(input>=k){
            int extra = input/k;
            bonus += extra;
            input += extra - (k*extra);
        }
        int total = n1 + bonus;
        printf("%d\n", total);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. https://wiki.c2.com/?DeclareVariablesAtFirstUse

Comment: It did work, I messed up with the formula too after some testing. But you telling me about the declaration stuff helped too!